# jsconfig.json error: "node_modules/html-entities/lib/index" not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-jsconfig

This is my `jsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "paths": {
        "@analytics/*": ["./src/analytics/*"],
        "@assets/*": ["./src/assets/*"],
        "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
        "@constants/*": ["./src/constants/*"],
        "@cookies/*": ["./src/cookies/*"],
        "@helpers/*": ["./src/helpers/*"],
        "@helmet/*": ["./src/helmet/*"],
        "@hooks/*": ["./src/hooks/*"],
        "@layout/*": ["./src/layout/*"],
        "@pages/*": ["./src/pages/*"],
        "@redux/*": ["./src/redux/*"],
        "@routes/*": ["./src/routes/*"],
        "@styles/*": ["./src/styles/*"],
        "@src/*": ["./src/*"]
      }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*", "scripts"
  ]
}
```

This file is triggering this 3 instances of the same error.

`"node_modules/html-entities/lib/index" not found`

[image]

What is happening? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: I've had similar errors. Try restart vscode or Try add `exclude` property. ref: [jsconfig\.json Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-the-exclude-property)

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue. Restaring VScode fix the problem.

Comment: yup, that's it, worked for me! Truly a universal fix after all